# Building data warehouse dimension

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2, data-warehouse

I'm trying to create a data warehouse from which we will create all business reports. Already learned quite a lot about this and I have a general idea how to build the data warehouse. However, I came across a problem when I started to wonder how I could combine into a single data store information about products and sales from two separate OLTP databases.

ETL process looks like this:
1 Transfer product data from the first OLTP database table stgProducts
2 Merg product data from table to table stgProducts dimProducts - if the product is changed records are updated when there are new products that are added to new records.
3 Transfer product data from another database OLTP table stgProducts
4 Merg product data from table to table stgProducts dimProducts - if the product is changed records are updated when there are new products that are added to new records.

Similarly, the transfer is realized on sales data.

If I have one table with products how do I connect to the sales data from two different databases?

Speaking of the two databases, I mean two different ERP systems. One manages the online sales, the other handles other sales. SKU of the product is the same but the product ID is different for each system.

Comment: The ETL process needs to normalize / map product ID keys to the unified product table in the warehouse.  This is **the** job of the ETL process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're using a star schema (not always the best approach, BTW), your product dimension table should have a key that is unique to the DW.  Thus, SKU 186 might have a DW-specific key of 1 and SKU 294 might have a DW-specific key of 2.  Your fact table, which holds 'transaction records' (sales records?), will have a compound key composed of multiple foreign key columns (eg. product_key, date_key, location_key, etc.).

This foreign key to the product table in this case is to the DW-specific product key, NOT to the source system SKU.

The ETL to populate your fact table should 'translate' the source system product key into the DW-specific product key as you bring the data in.

NOTE: This is the general approach to populating fact tables.  There can be variations based on specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding Bens answer a bit with the caveate the there is no right answer the data warehouse - it is an expansive, mungeable area of IT with lots of schools of thought. Here is one possible direction you can pursue.

Assumptions:
1) You have 2 separate source databases both with 2 tables: Product and Sales
2) The separate source database are isloated and may have conflicting primary key data.
3) You want to version[1] both the product and the sales tables. This is an important assumption as *mostly* fact tables are not updated and the sales table sounds like it belongs as a nice static fact table. Your question in unclear on if you are expecting changes to sales so I will assume you will
4) A sales record can only ever be of 1 product (this is unlikely, but your question only mentions the 2 tables so ill work from there, a 1-many relation will involve more tweaking around the bridging table)

Warehouse Design:

You will need 3 tables with the following columns:

**PRODUCT_DIM**

- PRODUCT_SK *(Surrogate primary key data warehouse database generated)*
- SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID *(DW specific indicator as to which source OLTP database the record was sourced from - can be string if you like)*
- PRODUCT_NK *(PK of product from source system, used for SCD operations)*
- DATE_FROM *(Record active from)*
- DATE_TO *(Record active to (null for current))*
- PRODUCT_NAME *(Product name for source table)*
- *Other Columns (Any other product columns you may need)*

**SALES DIM**
 - SALES_SK *(Surrogate primary key Data warehouse database generated)*
 - SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID *(DW specific indicator as to which source OLTP database the record was sourced from - can be string if you like)* 
 - SALES_NK *(PK of sales record from source system, used for SCD operations)*
 - DATE_FROM *(Record active from)*
 - DATE_TO *(Record active to (null for current))*
 - SALE_AMOUNT *(Product name for source table)*
 - *Other Columns (Any other sales columns you may need)*

**PRODUCT_SALES_BRIDGE**
 - PRODUCT_SK *(composite primary key)*
 - SALES_SK *(composite primary key)*
 - DATE_FROM *(Record active from)*
 - DATE_TO *(Record active to (null for current))*

The main things to note is the identifiers in the SALES and PRODUCT dim tables.

There is a Natural Key column for storing each records Primary Key value as exactly whats in the source system.

Because you have stated you have multiple source systems, the additional SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID column is required so you can match records from your multiple source systems to their equivalent record in your warehouse. Otherwise you might have a product of EGGS with an ID of 13 in your first source system  and a product called MILK with an ID also of 13 in your second system. Without the additional SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID you will be forever cutting records for PRODUCT_DIM natural key 13. This will look somthing like this in your warehouse:

```
PRODUCT_SK  SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID PRODUCT_NK   ..  PRODUCT_NAME
..
14                1          13           ..  EGGS            
15                2          13           ..  MILK
..
```

The bridge table exists to prevent cutting of new SALES or PRODUCT records each time their related record changes. Consider a sale of 10$ with of Red Eggs. The next data, the Red Eggs product is renamed to "Super Red Eggs". This will result in a new PRODUCT record for Red Eggs in the warehouse. If the SALES table included a direct link to PRODUCT_SK, a new SALES record would to be cut solely because there was a new product SK for our Red Eggs. The bridging table moves the Referential Integrity Induced cutting of a new record from the DIMENSION/FACT table into the bridge table. This also has the added benfit of making new comers to the datawarehouse very aware that they are operating in a different mindset to the traditional RDBMS.

The 2 Natural Key columns should assist you to solve your original question, the bridge table is just personal preference and added for completeness - If you have a DW design already that works for you, stick with it.

[1] Ill use version to refer to mean what ever slowly changing dimension methodology you choose. Most people cheap out and just Type2 their entire tables 'just in case'